# How do I prevent uncatchable exceptions in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, if an exception is rethrown in an async context, the exception is not catchable.
This can easily be seen by using Flutter to display an Image.network() widget with an incorrect url. Flutter will load the image in async, get the error, handle it (ie show the errorBuilder) but then rethrow the image.

That rethrown error is not catchable by a specific try {} catch() {} block.

The problem occurs anytime you try to load something from the web, and the dev thought rethrowing the error was a good idea : HttpClient().getUrl() has the problem,  _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter() has the problem, etc... but most if not all of these errors are entirely unless. How can I avoid them, or at least catch them in the relevant context ?

I've raised an issue with the Flutter team saying they should at least provide a boolean allowing us to deactivate the rethrow for the cases where it's not needed, without luck : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111996

Comment: had you a look at this related github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118586 specifically the answer by iapicca. I don't have flutter on my current machine but I can look later if I remember

Comment: @Kevin I did see it, but it just occurred to me that since precacheImage returns a Future I could then use catchError on it. That might work, but unfortunately I'd have to implement this everywhere, which is still quite annoying... And by everywhere, I mean that there's external packages concerned too. But it's a good bandaid.

Comment: Do you have an example of `HttpClient().getUrl()` exhibiting this problem?  I get catchable `SocketException`s if the URL is not resolvable or if the connection is refused.